# Help finding value of N that minimizes a sum

Tags: probability, optimization, summation

Suppose we have the following inequality:

$\sum\limits_{k=N+1}^{1000}\binom{1000}{k}(\frac{1}{2})^{k}(\frac{1}{2})^{1000-k} = \frac{1}{2^{1000}}\sum\limits_{k=N+1}^{1000}\binom{1000}{k} < \frac{1}{100}$

Is there a program that can calculate the smallest value of N that makes the above true? This is related to probability and the binomial distribution with $X \sim B({1000},{0.5}$).

Comment: you could use any CAS (Maple, Mathematica, MatLab, etc.) t owrite a little code and get the result, is not heavy for computer calculations.

Answer (score 1):

The central limit theorem says that $X$ binomial $(1000,.5)$ is $X=500+5\sqrt{10}Z$ with $Z$ approximately standard normal. Using the `erf`function, this suggests that $N$ is around $536.7$.

WA indicates $0.01046$ for $N=536$ and $0.00833$ for $N=537$ hence the solution is $N=\color{red}{537}$.

---

`sum of binom(1000,k)/2^(1000) from k=537 to k=1000`

Decimal approximation:

`0.0104635553030424713317175500708088450031910719508853`

---

`sum of binom(1000,k)/2^(1000) from k=538 to k=1000`

Decimal approximation:

`0.0088311156677493199532392344343609404372379787296116`

Comment: If I think mine is useful, then so is yours :-) (+1)

Comment: @robjohn I do not understand your comment. Not that it matters much.

Comment: I was simply noting that our answers were along the same lines (approximating by a normal distribution to make an initial guess). Since the criterion for upvoting is "This answer is useful", I was making what I thought was a humorous comment while upvoting your answer.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, I neglected to mention that there is another part to this question. The second asks to use the normal approximation to verify the binomial answer.

Comment: @user122088: I think both Did and I have done that. We have both used the normal distribution approximation and the actual binomial distribution.

Comment: @robjohn: Sorry, I should be more clear. I meant the first part asks to solve for N as given without any assumptions or approximations. The second part says to use the normal approximation to verify the first part. I believe you have answered the second part of the question.

Comment: @user122088: we answered the first part with the aid of the second part. Because we had the normal approximation, we only needed to check a couple of cases rather than checking the $465$ cases from $1000$ to $536$. We actually computed $$\frac1{2^{1000}}\sum_{k=537}^{1000}\binom{1000}{k}=0.01046$$ and $$\frac1{2^{1000}}\sum_{k=538}^{1000}\binom{1000}{k}=0.00883$$ which answers the first part of the question.

Comment: @user122088: perhaps the last part of my answer is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The sum approximates the Normal distribution with mean of $500$ and variance of $250$. Using the cumulative normal distribution, $1\%$ is higher than $2.326$ standard deviations above the mean. That would be about $500+2.326\sqrt{250}=536.7$. Since this is greater than $536.5$, we should guess that $N=537$ would satisfy the given condition.

Plugging in $N=536$ into the binomial sum, we get $0.01046$, and for $N=537$, we get $0.00883$. So our guess was correct; we need $N=537$.

---

To approximate
$$
\frac1{2^{1000}}\sum_{k=537}^{1000}\binom{1000}{k}
$$
we compute the amount of the cumulative normal distribution higher than $\frac{536.5-500}{\sqrt{250}}=2.30846$ standard deviations above the mean, which is $0.01049$.

To approximate
$$
\frac1{2^{1000}}\sum_{k=538}^{1000}\binom{1000}{k}
$$
we compute the amount of the cumulative normal distribution higher than $\frac{537.5-500}{\sqrt{250}}=2.37171$ standard deviations above the mean, which is $0.00885$.